# Unable to create a private chain

Tags: private

I am trying to create a private chain. this are my details

```
{
    "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "difficulty": "0x4000",
    "alloc": {
    "xxxxxxx": {
        "balance": "10000000000000000000"
        }
    },
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "Custem Ethereum Genesis Block",
    "gasLimit": "0xffffffff"
}
```

I then did  `geth --datadir eth-data --networkid 123 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 console init genesis.json`

But my ether is still 0/. What is going on

Comment: you can use `puppeth` to easily generate the genesis file

Comment: btw, `xxxxxxx` is real value or you just to make a censorship?

Comment: its a fake value.  but then my accounts are still reading 0 even though i have initualised?

Comment: @Adam Try initializing in an empty directory. If it was previously initialized it will not initialize again. How are you checking the balances?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**File genesis.json:**

```
{
   "config": {
      "chainId": 100,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0
   },
   "difficulty": "0",
   "gasLimit": "0xfffffffffff",
   "alloc": {
        "PUBLIC_KEY_1": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_2": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_3": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_4": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_5": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_6": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_7": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},
        "PUBLIC_KEY_8": {"balance": "1000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
    }
}
```

**Call from command-line one time:**

```
geth --datadir=.\data init .\genesis.json
```

**Call from command-line every time you want to start the node:**

```
geth.exe --networkid=100 --rpc --rpcport=8545 --lightkdf --mine --datadir=./data
```

You can add `--verbosity=2` if you want to have a small amount of debug-printouts.

You can add `--verbosity=5` if you want to have a large amount of debug-printouts.

Comment: Of course, use your actual public keys (wallet addresses) up there.

Answer (score 0):

I know linking is not considered an answer but I'm not a fan of copy pasting bits of the article either...

https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8